# Include methods from another node header (C++)

Tags: c++, ros-melodic, include, nodes, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node with some methods declared in `/include/node_1.h` and defined in `/src/node_1.cpp`. Now, I want to include that header into another node `/src/node_2.cpp` and use the methods there, like:

```
// node_2.cpp
#include "pkgname/node_1.h"

// ...
some_method_from_node_1();
```

I can `catkin_make` with including, but I get a linker error (undefined reference to the method) when trying to compile while calling the method from node_2.

My `CMakeLists.txt` for the package looks like:

```
# ...

## declare a catkin package
catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)

## include dirs
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

## nodes
set(NODES
    node_1
    node_2
)

foreach(node IN LISTS NODES)
    
    add_executable(${node} src/${node}.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${node} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
    add_dependencies(${node} hric_sys_generate_messages_cpp)

endforeach()
```

How can I make it work and is this approach even idiomatically correct?

**EDIT:**

So, I have a method called `my_test_func()`, which I can call from `node_1` but get a linker error if I try to invoke it from `node_2`, although the include works. This is the (simplified) code:

`include/node_1.h`:

```
# pragma once

void my_test_func();
```

`src/node_1.cpp`:

```
#include "package/node_1.h"

void my_test_func()
{
    ROS_INFO("API CALL!");
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    my_test_func(); // WORKS
}
```

`src/node_2.cpp`:

```
#include "package/node_1.h"

int main()
{
    // ...
    my_test_func(); // DOESN'T WORK
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345338/include-methods-from-another-node-header-(c++)/) by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2020-02-28**:
So the linker can't find the function. Are you sure that the function is defined correctly and that it can be called. E.g. can you call it in node_1? If you also put your header and source files here, it is more easy to answer your question.

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-02-28**:
It worked from node_1, yes, and I could include the method in node_2. I didn't upload the full code, because I simplified the problem with different names. I think the error might have been making the method definition in node_1 `inline`. I will check that on Monday.

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-03-02**:
So, I added some example code below.. It still doesn't work, even if the method is not inlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a function `my_test_func()` declared in `node_1.h` and implemented in `node_1.cpp`.
When you try to use it in `node_2.cpp`, the linker is missing it's implementation, as only declaration in `node_1.h` is known, but implementation of that function is missing.

To solve this you have 2 options:

- remove implementation of `my_test_func()` from `node_1.cpp` and add it to `node_1.h` file (so that function is declared and implemented in header file)
- Create a class `Node1` (`in node_1.h`/`cpp`) with  `my_test_func()` public member function of that class. Then create an instance of this class in `node_2.cpp` and call `my_test_func()` as member of this class, i.e.

  #include "package/node_1.h"

  int main()
  {
  // ...
  Node1 n1;
  n1.my_test_func();
  }

---

Originally posted by [Thazz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39841/thazz/) with karma: 66 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-03**:
It's the same option in the end, eventhough you create a class the implementation of the function would need to be in the header file to have this working. It's a general good practice not to mix declaration and implementation.

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-03-03**:
So, defining the method in the header file works, although I don't understand why it doesn't result in a multiple-definitions error. Also, I want to modify some data (e.g. a vector in `node_1.cpp`) using an interface/function calls from `node_2`, but maybe ROS is not made for that?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-03**:\

> maybe ROS is not made for that?

`ROS` *is a collection of tools, libraries, and conventions* (from [ROS.org](https://www.ros.org/about-ros/)) so you can do whatever you want with `ROS` using `C++` or `Python`.

It looks like you need to use classes, I would advise you to learn the basics of `Object-Oriented Programming` and `C++` before getting into `ROS`, wihtout this background using `ROS` would be very challenging.

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-03-03**:
I'm basically trying to call `node_1`'s methods from `node_2` that will alter some internal data structure of `node_1`, e.g. `node1::add_something()`. I am not sure that ROS is designed for that without using messages or services. Also, `OOP` is not really relevant here; if anything, `node_1` is a utility class.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-04**:\

> I am not sure that ROS is designed for that without using messages or services

ROS is designed to do this with messages or services.

Now with your additionnal inputs I feel we are diverging from your original question ("include methdods from another header"), if one of the two answers has answered this specific question you can mark it as correct.

For your other question(s) I still don't see what is your blocking point, with our suggestions you still can't call methods of `node_1` from `node_2` ? I would advise you to open a new question describing your whole problematic in details, telling us what you have tried so far and what your errors/issues are.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To re-use functions that have been implemented in another `cpp` file you need to have this file compiled as a library. That's exactly what `catkin_make` tells you with the error `undefined reference to ...`. Basically, during the compilation all the directives `#include` get replaced by the content of the included file, so here you end up with `node_1` having the declaration and implementation of the function `my_test_func` in the executable but not for `node_2`. So when you call `my_test_func()` in `node_2` you don't know its implementation. What you need to do is having `node_1.cpp` compiled as a library. In that case you will link the library to `node_2.cpp` that will get the implementation of the function.

Your `CMakeLists.txt` should be :

```
# Declare the library node_1
add_library(node_1 src/node_1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(node_1 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(node_1 hric_sys_generate_messages_cpp)

# Declare the executable node_2 and link it to node_1
add_executable(node_2 src/node_2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(node_2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES} node_1)
add_dependencies(node_2 hric_sys_generate_messages_cpp)

# Declare the executable node_1_exe if you still want to run node_1
# You don't need to link it to the library node_1 since the implementation
# of the function will be in node_1.cpp
add_executable(node_1_exe src/node_2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(node_1_exe ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(node_1_exe hric_sys_generate_messages_cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-03-03**:
This is pretty much what I've found out as well.. I think that I will turn `node_1` into a separate package and compile it as a library, since I want an interface to it. But can I still run `node_1` as a ROS node, even if it's compiled as a library (or something alike)?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-03**:\

> can I still run node_1 as a ROS node, even if it's compiled as a library

If it's only compiled as a library then no (meaning only `add_library`), you can only use `rosrun` if there is `add_executable`.

In my example the library `node_1` allows you to use the methods from `node_1.cpp` (thanks to `add_library.(..))` if other nodes need it but you can also use `rosrun package node_1_exe` to run `node_1.cpp` alone (thanks to `add_executable(..)`). I admit the naming is bad but in the end `node_1` is the library and `node_1_exe` is the executable, these are two different entities generated from `node1.cpp`.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-03**:\

> I think that I will turn node_1 into a separate package

I don't see the point to that. But I also don't see why you would want to use `node1.cpp` as a library and an executable too you might want to rethink your design. Maybe we are running into an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

**Comment by [martinandrovich](https://answers.ros.org/users/52136/martinandrovich/) on 2020-03-03**:
You might be correct that it is not the correct design approach; essentially I am creating a data synchronizer that can *dynamically* register nodes; here `node_1` is the main application where `node_2` would be some aux node that tries to register itself during run-time, i.e. from `node_2` calling: `node1::register(args)`.

I specifically want to use method calls and not ROS messages or services. Or maybe there's some other method that I don't know of.